# PHP: Autoloading PEAR namespaced classes within PSR-0 namespaced classes conflict

Tags: php, namespaces, pear, autoloader, psr-0

For my application I am using PSR-0 namespaces. Everything works beautiful!

Until I wanted to use Twig as template parser, Twig uses PEAR pseudo namespaces. Like Twig_Loader_Filesystem.

The problem is that when I want to use Twig inside my name-spaced application like this:

```
<?php
namespace Tact\ViewManager;

class ViewManager {

    public function init()
    {
        $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($this->templatepath);
        $this->twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
    }  
}
?>
```

PHP will tell my autoloader to look for an class named `Tact\ViewManager\Twig_Loader_Filesystem`

**How can I manage to autoload PEAR name-spaced style classes without the PSR-0 namespace of the invoking class?**

My autoloader is able to load both PEAR and PSR-0..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are in the `Tact\ViewManager` namespace.
The pseudo-namespaced classes are in fact in the global namespace,
so you should prefix them with `\` to call them:

```
$loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem($this->templatepath);
```

If the `\` prefix bugs you, you could do this:

```
namespace Tact\ViewManager;

use Twig_Loader_Filesystem;
use Twig_Environment;

class ViewManager {
    public function init()
    {
        $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($this->templatepath);
        $this->twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I already tried that but than my autoloader will detect the `\` prefix and tries to include it the PSR-0 way.. I am afraid your solution is the only solution to get things working..

Comment: Quote: "I am afraid your solution is the only solution to get things working", did it work or not? What do you mean by "including it the PSR-0" way. Where does it look for the class? Could you edit the post to show the autoloader code (the bit where you transform the namespaces into directories)?

Comment: Sorry, you were right. It works!  But as I said before. It looks really ugly :P

Comment: Nice solution! Did not even think of that. U made my day:)

Comment: @igorw corrupted your answer to be not functional

Comment: @WoutvanderVegt Sorry about that, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem($this->templatepath);
    $this->twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);
```

This will tell PHP to force namespace\class lookup at "root" level, and if your autoloader is setup to load both namespaces and regular PEAR convention classnames it will work.

Comment: My autoloader indeed gets the class name without the namespace prefix. So things can work now. But it looks so damn ugly.. Thanks!